problem trying to follow spring security tutorial on spring.io
I am trying to follow this tutorial.. I downloaded the startup project. it is gradle project but the tutorial says it is maven.
I imported it in eclipse as existing gradle project. The tutorial says run it as in server to make sure it is working. But this option is not available. The project only contain integration test code.The java class has compile error on Webdriver. I do not know how to solve this. Please help me to get into right track for this first step

That sample is out of date and not maintained. It is not linked from anywhere else in our website that I know of. Out of curiosity, how did you find it?
If you truly need an XML example for how to configure spring security, please see this xml sample. However, we have other samples that I would recommend over the xml configuration example. You may also find Spring Academy useful. It is free to create an account and browse all of the tutorials and courses.

Thanks Steve; the link is there I see it every day. I am following spring  3 course in Udemy  and the custom log in did not work as the instructor  is showing in video. so i searched to make it work on my side and found what I am talking about. I want real (legacy) solution  sample. I hope what you suggested is what I want. will check it and come back

Hi Steve the xml sample is too complicated for me. I want simple abc example. we look the rest
